# Javascript execute timer function only if window is in focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have two separate browser windows open:

```
function onload() {
    setTimeout("dosomething", 2000);
}

function dosomething() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "someurl",
        success: function (data) {
            document.write("Hello");
        }
    });
    setTimeout("dosomething", 2000);
}
```

I want to make it so that hello is printed every two seconds only when the window is in focus. If the window is not in focus, then the timer would essentially pause (in other words, timer would stop ticking, dosomething would not be called) until the user clicks on the browser window that is not in focus, which the timer would resume and the Hello words would continue to be printed, while the other window would stop timer, vice versa.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky one, and depend on browser.

```
var timer;    
function onBlur() {
    timer = setTimeout("dosomething", 2000);
};
function onFocus(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
};
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
    document.onfocusin = onFocus;
    document.onfocusout = onBlur;
} else {
    window.onfocus = onFocus;
    window.onblur = onBlur;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var someVar = false;
window.onfocus = function() { someVar = true; };
window.onblur = function() { someVar = false; };
var time;

function timer(someVar) {
    if (someVar == true) {
        setTimeOut('time++', 1);
    }
}

function something() {
    time = 0;
    while (time <= 2000) {
        timer(someVar);
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time;
    }
}
```